# VBA Loop requiring user to enter a new sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, loops, input

I am currently creating a new sheet and having the user name it with a unique sheet name. I have a loop that checks once and prompts the user to enter a new sheet name if it is wrong the first time, but I don't know how to restart the loop once this happens.

```
Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Enter New Sheet Name")
    
    Dim exists As Boolean
    exists = True
While exists = True
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = myValue Then
            exists = True
            myValue = InputBox("You entered an existing sheet name. Please enter a unique sheet name")
        Else
        exists = False
        End If
        Next i
    i = 1
Wend

Sheets("NewSheet").Name = myValue

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using the worksheet renaming error handling method, you get the fastest and shortest way to determine the uniqueness and acceptability of a name, since there are character composition and name length [restrictions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9).
Try this code:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim newWS As Worksheet, myValue As String, prompt As String
    prompt = "Enter New Sheet Name"     'start prompt
    
    Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    Do
        myValue = InputBox(prompt)
        On Error Resume Next            'disable the system response to errors
        newWS.Name = myValue            'trying to rename
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Do  'check the Err object; if no error then exit loop
        On Error GoTo 0                 'enable the system response to errors
        prompt = "You entered an existing or unacceptable sheet name." & _
                 vbLf & "Please enter a unique sheet name"  'next try prompt
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateNewWorksheet()
    Dim newName As String
    newName = InputBox("Enter the new sheet name:")
    
    Dim waitingForUniqueName As Boolean
    waitingForUniqueName = True
    Do While waitingForUniqueName
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If ws.Name = newName Then
                newName = InputBox("You entered an existing sheet name. " & _
                                   "Please enter a unique sheet name.")
                waitingForUniqueName = True
                Exit For
            Else
                waitingForUniqueName = False
            End If
        Next ws
    Loop
    
    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    newWS.Name = newName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for using recursion. It just recalls the sub passing a value to an optional parameter until an unused name is chosen.

```
Sub test()

recurse_name

End Sub


Sub recurse_name(Optional ByVal myValue As String)
    Dim i As Long

    If myValue = "" Then
        myValue = InputBox("Enter New Sheet Name")
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = myValue Then
            myValue = InputBox("You entered an existing sheet name. Please enter a unique sheet name")
            recurse_name myValue
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    
    Sheets("NewSheet").Name = myValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a separate function, which could be used elsewhere, to check if a sheet with the entered name already exists.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RenameSheet()
Dim myValue As String
Dim exists As Boolean

    myValue = InputBox("Enter New Sheet Name")

    Do
        exists = SheetExists(myValue)
        If exists Then
            myValue = InputBox("You entered an existing sheet name. Please enter a unique sheet name")
        End If
    Loop Until Not exists

    Sheets("NewSheet").Name = myValue

End Sub

Function SheetExists(strName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) = LCase(strName) Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
End Function
```

Comment: If there is a chart in the workbook, your function will fail with a `type mismatch` error. Rather use `Dim ws As Object`.

Comment: I normally avoid that by looping through Worksheets rather than Sheets, but obviously didn't do that this time. I'll edit my code.

Comment: In this case, you have to loop through the `Sheets` collection because if a chart with the name exists, the result of the function will be wrong (`False`).

Comment: You are probably right but I'm not 100% sure what the questioner is actually trying to do here. In the code they posted all they seem to be doing is renaming a sheet called 'NewSheet' - there's nothing in the posted code that actually adds a new sheet. Perhaps they need to post the rest of the code to clarify the matter.

Answer (score 0):

### Add a New Worksheet

- You have more options with the flexible [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) e.g. you can easily distinguish between `""` and `Cancel` (`False`).
- By previously not adding the worksheet, you are allowing to cancel the operation (without the need to delete the worksheet).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewWorksheet()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Variant
    
    Do
        wsName = Application.InputBox( _
            "Enter New Sheet Name", "Sheet Name", "Sheet1", , , , 1)
        If wsName = False Then
            MsgBox "User canceled.", vbCritical
            Exit Do
        ElseIf IsSheetNameTaken(wb, wsName) Then
            MsgBox "A sheet named '" & wsName & "' already exists. " _
                 & "Please enter a unique sheet name.", vbExclamation
        ElseIf Not IsValidSheetName(wsName) Then
            MsgBox "The name '" & wsName & "' is invalid.", vbExclamation
        Else
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            ws.Name = wsName
            MsgBox "Added the '" & wsName & "' worksheet.", vbInformation
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' worksheet not added
    
    ' Continue with the code using the worksheet variable 'ws'.

End Sub


Function IsSheetNameTaken( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsSheetNameTaken = Not sh Is Nothing
End Function

Function IsValidSheetName( _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    If Len(SheetName) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Len(SheetName) > 31 Then Exit Function
    Const iCharsList As String = ":,\,/,?,*,[,] "
    Dim iChars() As String: iChars = Split(iCharsList, ",")
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(iChars)
        If InStr(1, SheetName, iChars(n)) > 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next n
    IsValidSheetName = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code makes array of sheet names and with Instr function checks if the sheeet with the given name already exists. If so, it will again prompt to enter a new name with error message. New sheet will not be added until user enters a new name. User will have option to exit the sub with empty inputbox without adding the new sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheetWithGivenName()
Dim SheetNamesStr As String, IBPrompt As String, NewSheetName As String

If IsError(Evaluate("SheetNames")) Then
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SheetNames", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=MID(GET.WORKBOOK(1),FIND(""]"",GET.WORKBOOK(1),1)+1,LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1)))"
End If
SheetNamesStr = "," & Join(Evaluate("SheetNames"), ",") & ","

IBPrompt = "Enter New Sheet Name"

InputSheetName:

NewSheetName = InputBox(IBPrompt, "New Sheet Name")

If NewSheetName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    If InStr(1, SheetNamesStr, "," & NewSheetName & ",", vbBinaryCompare) Then
    IBPrompt = "Sheet name already exists !!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Please enter new sheet name"
    GoTo InputSheetName
    End If
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    .Name = NewSheetName
End With

End Sub
```

[image]